# ASP.NET state service storing data

Tags: asp.net, .net, session

In outproc mode using ASP.NET state service, the value session values are stored in Key value pair.

**Where are they stored ?**

**Do we have any in memory database to perform this operation ?**

Comment: I don't see outproc as a valid option in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where are they stored? Do we have any in memory database to perform this operation ?

In StateServer mode, data are serialized, and stored in an in-memory dictionary-based object.

It can be on same machine as web server or different machine in Web farm.

Comment: What will be the max size and the scalable limit for this dictionary based object.

Comment: There is no max size. If you store too many, server will eventually throw OutOfMemory Exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the "StateServer" session state mode, then the session values are stored in a separate process, which is technically a windows service (ASP.NET state service).

In the beginning of each request, the web server will request the session values from the State Service and populate the Session object.

In the end of each request, the web server will use the current Session object to update the session values on the State Service.